# Java context class loader and external file

Tags: java, classpath

I want to be able to read files from the classpath both inside my IDE and when executing the application jar outside of any IDE.
Inside my application I defined a method for reading from the context class loader:

```
private static URL getResourceUrl(String arg) {
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL resource = loader.getResource(arg);
    if (resource == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Bad filename provided");
    }
    return resource;
}
```

It works well inside my IDE, but when I execute the generated jar of my application outside of the IDE I run into `throw new RuntimeException("Bad filename provided");`

The jar is generated by maven.

Here is the command line I use in a terminal window:

```
java -cp ~/inputs/ -jar my-app.jar my-file-to-read.txt
```

and also

```
java -cp ~/inputs/ -jar my-app.jar /path/to/inputs/my-file-to-read.txt
```

and

```
java -cp "/path/to/inputs/:/path/to/inputs/my-file-to-read.txt" -jar my-app.jar /path/to/inputs/my-file-to-read.txt
```

How to write code so that my application can read both from my IDE and when running in a standalone mode ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use absolute path for my-file-to-read.txt, something like c:\my_dir\my-file-to-read.txt

Comment: Thank you but it is not changing anything.

Comment: try to add the resource file to the classpath, like: -cp ~/my-inputs/;/path/to/input/my-file-to-read.txt